# Import the data from the XML files into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xml

I would like to build a Rails application to import the data from a XML file into a MySQL database. Any help?

Comment: Import it into an ORM that accepts XML, and save.

Comment: A noob here. Any code that you can point me to?

Comment: Did you try http://www.google.com/search?q=ORM+import+XML+ruby?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050873/nokogiri-xml-import-feed-organisation

Comment: do you want the raw xml to be stored?

Comment: @Aditya: Tell us more about your needs. Why do you think you need rails? The more details in the question, the more useful answers you will receive.

Comment: @Arsen7 The Users will upload XML sheets and it should get stored in our database. Rails coz we have an app that runs on MySQL and Rails. Now, this XML import module should let the user import the XML data which in turn will go to the database and will be used by the app which we already built. Hope i made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need Rails for this task? Will the XML file be uploaded by users? If not, then a script in ruby may be all you need.

In all cases you need to:

- parse incoming XML and set the properties of some object or variables
- save these properties or variables in the database.

For the first task you may use ReXML, [LibXML](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/), [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html) or any other XML parser library.

For the second (if you don't use ActiveRecord in Rails), you may see the documentation for the [mysql2 gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2).

Feel free to ask further questions if you have any problems with these libraries.